# Custom Data Annotations inheritance for reusablity

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

Say you have a class with an property for Email, with some Data Annotations

```
public class Person
{
    [Display(Name = "Email address")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "The email address is required")]
    [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Invalid Email Address")]
    [CustomDataAnnotation()]
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

Now you need another class with an Email property with the same Data Annotations

```
public class Invoice
    {
        [Display(Name = "Email address")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "The email address is required")]
        [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Invalid Email Address")]
        [CustomDataAnnotation()]
        public string Email { get; set; }
    }
```

Is there a way to create a new Data Annotation [MyEmail] that inherits all the other Data Annotations? Something like this

```
    [Display(Name = "Email address")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "The email address is required")]
    [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Invalid Email Address")]
    [CustomDataAnnotation()]
    public DataAnnoation MyEmail {get;set;}
```

And then be able to reuse it like this.

```
public class Person
    {
        [MyEmail]
        public string Email { get; set; }
    }

public class Invoice
    {
        [MyEmail]
        public string Email { get; set; }
    }
```

I know its possible to use an abstract class, but I don't like hidding the Email Property in another class making it harder to read.

```
public abstract class MyEmail
{
    [Display(Name = "Email address")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "The email address is required")]
    [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Invalid Email Address")]
    [CustomDataAnnotation()]
    public string Email { get; set; }
}

public class Person : MyEmail {}
public class Invoice : MyEmail { }
```

Any suggestings for making the Data Annotations more reusable is appreciated.

Comment: Did you check the official documentation? I am pretty sure it is explained there!

Comment: @PetrosApotsos Can you provide a link?

Comment: There may be instances where you need more features than built-in attributes provide. For those times, you can create custom validation attributes by deriving from ValidationAttribute or changing your model to implement IValidatableObject.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/el-gr/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation

Comment: @PetrosApotsos I know about creating custom validation, but I'm looking for a way to take a list of DataAnnotations and combining them into a new reusable Data Annotation.

Comment: @PetrosApotsos if I used IValidatableObject how would i handle the Display DataAnnotation?

Comment: @AndersGulbæk did you solve the problem?

Comment: @user8175473 yes ended up using your answer with MetadataType

Comment: I am glad to hear that :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `[MetadataType]` attribute on top of your Person and Invoice class to use your `MyEmail` class data.annatotaions attributes. You can implement like following.

```
[MetadataType(typeof(MyEmail))]
public class Person
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
}

[MetadataType(typeof(MyEmail))]
public class Invoice
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
}

public abstract class MyEmail
{
    [Display(Name = "Email address")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "The email address is required")]
    [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Invalid Email Address")]
    [CustomDataAnnotation()]
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```